# Access child window elements events and properties mootools

Tags: mootools, mootools-events

I have a **popup window** that I need to access click, change or any other event as well as elements  values for input and move them to parent window element

**example popup window html:**

```
<a href="#" class="button">Add image</a>

<input type="text" id="imagelink" value="link_to_image" />
```

**parent window html:**

```
<img id="logo_image" src="default_image_link" />
```

**start js:**

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){ 


   $$('.button').addEvent('click', function(){
   var img_src =  $('imagelink').get('value');
    $('logo_image').set('src',img_src);

   });

});
```

when user clicks on a.button in child window , I need to replace src property of  parent window #logo_image  with value from input #imagelink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by accessing `window.opener` property of popup window which points to parent window:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('logo_image').setAttribute('src', img_src);
```

Or if you also have MooTools in parent window:

```
window.opener.$('logo_image').set('src',img_src);
```